# Deploying Symfony 4 Application to AWS Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, symfony, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tomcat8

I have a working Symfony 4.0.1 application running on PHP 7.1.14 (locally) that I would like to deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk using the EB CLI

I have a dist package of the application on my `master` git branch configured for production (vendor folder removed etc) that I am able to successfully deploy to Heroku. Now I need to deploy to AWS EB.

The AWS EB environment has already been set up (although I dont have access to the console). Some environment details are as follows:

```
Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-2::platform/Tomcat 8 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.7
Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0
```

At first, I was able to successfully deploy the application, but accessing the URL gave a 404 error for every page.

[image]
I did some googling and found a few articles describing the use of `.config` files. I have added one named `03_main.config` with the following contents.

```
commands:
    300-composer-update:
        command: "export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && composer.phar self-update -n"
container_commands:
    300-run-composer:
        command: "composer.phar install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader --prefer-dist --no-interaction"
    600-update-cache:
        command: "source .ebextensions/bin/update-cache.sh"
    700-remove-dev-app:
        command: "rm web/app_dev.php"
```

Deploying with this `.config` file gives the following deployment failure error:

```
ERROR: [Instance: i-0c5f61f41d55a18bc] Command failed on instance. Return code: 127 Output: /bin/sh: composer.phar: command not found. command 300-composer-update in .ebextensions/03-main.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

I understand the purpose of `.config` files but do not understand what additional configuration is needed for get this Symfony app running.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use the full path to composer like bellow :

`100-update-composer:
  command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update -n`